# How can I get cursor position in a textbox as a pixel value?

Tags: javascript, cursor-position

I'm trying to do something like that:[image]

When use enter "#" in the textbox, the colorpicker div must be opened in bottom of the cursor position. I can get the order of the cursor with element.selectionStart but it's not reliable way to do that. It must be a pixel value. Any suggestion?

Comment: Read the mouse pointer position.

Comment: However mouse pointer can be anywhere.

Comment: That's correct, but you can also determine where the textarea is.

Comment: The only element is textbox and I need the position of the cursor not the textbox. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the textfield will never scroll, you can simply replicate the font and box sizing of the textfield in a div positioned out of view, and then measure the size of a span with the same contents as the textfield.

Comment: Course this only works if the cursor is at the end of the line when the user types the trigger :/

Comment: I can do it with inputselector.selectionStart*6px+inputoffset.left and the cursor doesn't have to be at the end but I cannot be sure that whether the textbox scrolled horizontally or not. :/

Comment: It's the scrollability of the input element that's gonna get you, I think. Otherwise, it's fairly trivial to track indices of # and figure out where one was just added inside the string. Without knowing the scroll offset of the text, though, it might be impossible to know how far inside the box, visually speaking, the character is.

Comment: The second solution I posted (I deleted it actually) was wrong. As you said, it's impossible to get the pixel value if I don't measure the width for each character. :) Therefore I decided to show the colorpicker in the left-bottom corner. thanks.